# What's most efficient: a= len(x)*[""] or a= ["" for i in x]?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to have a list with multiple instances of the same "dummy" data that I'll replace afterwards (with a[index] = new data).

I came through with two ways of doing this.

```
a= len(x)*[""]
```

and

```
a= ["" for i in x]
```

How can I tell which one will be the best? Is there any difference in how they run?

Both seem to yield the exact same result.

I tried looking this up in the documentation, stack overflow and google in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can use the library [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to check for perfomance speed:

```
from timeit import timeit

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def usingLen():
    a = len(x)*[""]

def usingListComprehension():
    a = ["" for i in x]

print(timeit("usingLen()", setup="from __main__ import usingLen"))
print(timeit("usingListComprehension()", setup="from __main__ import usingListComprehension"))
```

The output is:

```
0.373054536
0.554289093
```

That means, executing 1 million of times `len(x)*[""]` takes 0.37 seconds while executing a 1 million of times `["" for i in x]` takes 0.55 seconds. Using `len` seems faster.

I can't exactly say you why, but I think it has to do with the iteration of the comprehension list. `len()` just count the size of the array and then multiply the item `""`, while the list comprehension must iterate for each element of the array (which you don't need) in order to create each `""` item, which sounds as a heavier task.

The second iterates for each element of the array **and** creates per each element an `""` item. While the first creates the *length of the array* number of times `""` item, in no moment check what is each item.

Comment: Now that's an answer! Thank you a lot, sir!